# Images don't go to "dist" folder after build

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs

I was building an app but I forgot to install parcel. After I install all the build and setup it I lose my images. In the main folder, name of the image like as below but in the **dist** folder is different - and not only 2 of 6 pictures that I'm using was changed. Can someone help me? Thank you!

**My HTML**

```
<img src="/img/dice-1.png" alt="Playing dice"
```

**The HTML of browser**

```
... src="/dice-1.ce53b4a3.png" ...
```

I change it from **JS** when dice is rolled:

```
dice.src = `/img/dice-${currDice}.png`;
```

**UPDATE**
Some more info after i run npm run start the buider folder dis get again only 1 from my images i re-code a lot stuff bot not changes again.

[image: From img folder i have to take all of the 6 images]

[image: In dist foled i get only 1 with hash]

**How to get all of them in the dist folder. Thank you.**

THE APP:
https://roll-dice-remastered.netlify.app/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue is that from my starting files i havet folder images and after parcel my images dont go into the dist folder. How to add them with dist "hash"

Comment: Modern bundlers will hash and tree-shake your assets as a feature, coming from experience with Webpack. This means they will add that code to the end of the filename and omit any files they think are unused. Turning it off could work but you will lose this feature and I don't know which option is for parceljs. Your other option is to a giant switch statement so that your bundler detects the files as used.

Comment: If i import images and use it something like import icons from /src/img../ ?